# Which of these sentences is better?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which of the following sentences is correct?

"I have a strong willed and determined personality that causes me to do my best to achieve my goals"

" My personality is strong willed and determined, to do my best to achieve my goals"

Comment: I'd prefer the second one (straight and simple) without using comma.

Comment: I would definitely prefer the first one.  The second (with the comma) is not well-formed, and without the comma it says that your personality is determined to do your best- which is not something I think a personality does.  Your personality may be a contributing factor in why **you** are determined to do your best, but your personality doesn't have a brain and therefore can't be *determined* to do anything.

Comment: But I would revise the first to say, "I have a strong will and a determined ..."

Comment: @Jim I meant 'willed and determined' as an adjective collectively. *Determined* there means *devoting full strength and concentrated attention to*. Something like - I am *strong and able* to do that. But maybe, your point is worth considering. Personality is the complex of all our attributes including mental/emotional and behavioral.

Comment: how about this sentence: "I have a strong will and determination that causes me to do my best to achieve my goals. "

Comment: @PotentialScientist- nice, maybe substitute *motivates* for *causes*.

Comment: I recommend “My determination drives me to achieve.” Being strong-willed is the same as being determined, the only difference being that “strong-willed” carries the possible negative interpretation that you force your views on others. As others have said “causes” is too general, so I've switched it do “drives”. To “do [your] best” is not always a positive thing, as it is often provided as an excuse for not doing more and doesn't provide any information to someone who doesn't know what your “best” represents. I've eliminated “my goals” because I think it is stronger as a more general statement.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem natural to say that your personality causes you or motivates you to do anything. I would change it to "I have a strong will and a determined personality; I strive to achieve my goals."

Comment: Your sentence is stronger and more concise than mine.  However, the point you're making in your first sentence is a bit of a philosophical one.  One could argue that your second sentence disagrees with the position (which you haven't exactly taken) that personality doesn't cause or motivate one to do anything: it simply implies rather than stating that the effect of the determined personality is the striving to achieve goals.  If so, then the personality is indeed the cause of that effect.

Comment: Philosophically speaking, I agree with you. Grammatically speaking, it's still awkward to put it that way. :p

Answer (score 2):

A third possibility, that simplifies the first without changing the meaning as much as the second: "My strong-willed and determined personality causes me to do my best to achieve my goals."  I would also use "motivates" instead of "causes", personally.

I don't think the second example you give makes a heck of a lot of sense.  You'd have to say "which causes me to do my best" rather than just "to do my best".  That gets wordy again, which is what you were trying to avoid when you changed the first example.